# A Game of a Combination Lock (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, locking, combinations

Im am making a riddle game, and I need to make a lock combination with six digits in *JavaScript*. I can't find a way to make a correct combination. I tried to make 6 different variables, each one with ten possible numbers (from 0 to 9). The thing is: when I write the *javascript*, I use an `if statement` with the conditions `(n1==0 && n2==0 && n3==0 && n4==0 && n5==0 && n6==0)` to change a `div`'s `id` when all the conditions were `true`, but that doesn´t seem to work. 
I saw a code (https://codepen.io/MrHill/pen/kLvcw) that has a similar lock combination as mine. The coder used an `array` with the whole combination but I actually didn´t understood quite well the code and I would prefer to used separated `variables`. Do I have to use an `array` or is there a way to write an `if statement` like I am at the moment?
Should I use jQuery, or should I stick to JS?

#### Here is my code:

```js
var n1 = 1;
var n2 = 3;
var n3 = 2;
var n4 = 1;
var n5 = 1;
var n6 = 1;

document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = n1;
document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = n2;
document.getElementById("number3").innerHTML = n3;
document.getElementById("number4").innerHTML = n4;
document.getElementById("number5").innerHTML = n5;
document.getElementById("number6").innerHTML = n6;

function incN1() {
    if (n1>9) {
        n1 = 0;
        document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = n1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = n1++;
    }
}

function incN2() {
    if (n2>9) {
        n2 = 0;
        document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = n2;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = n2++;
    }
}

function incN3() {
    if (n3>9) {
        n3 = 0;
        document.getElementById("number3").innerHTML = n3;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("number3").innerHTML = n3++;
    }
}

function incN4() {
    if (n4>9) {
        n4 = 0;
        document.getElementById("number4").innerHTML = n4;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("number4").innerHTML = n4++;
    }
}

function incN5() {
    if (n5>9) {
        n5 = 0;
        document.getElementById("number5").innerHTML = n5;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("number5").innerHTML = n5++;
    }
}

function incN6() {
    if (n6>9) {
        n6 = 0;
        document.getElementById("number6").innerHTML = n6;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("number6").innerHTML = n6++;
    }
}

function ups() {
    alert("It's locked! Try to find the combination to find out what this locker hides!");
}

if (n1==0 && n2==0 && n3==0 && n4==0 && n5==0 && n6==0) {
    document.getElementById('lock').id = "unlock";
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}
#container {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 position: fixed;
}
#halfCircle {
 background-color: black;
 border: 24px solid #777;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 100px 0 0 500px;
}
#lock {
 width: 35px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: black;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 720px;
 margin-top: -140px;
 display: none;
}
#unlock {
 width: 35px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: black;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 720px;
 margin-top: -140px;
}
#locker {
 background-color: #d4af37;
 border: 2px solid #404040;
 border-radius: 2px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: -120px 0 0 473px;
}
#code {
 margin: -190px 0 0 495px;
 float: auto;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select:none;
 user-select:none;
 -o-user-select:none;
}
#number1 {
 background-color: #777;
 margin-left: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #404040;
 border-radius: 4px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 80px;
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Roboto Mono;
 font-weight: lighter;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
#number1:hover {
 background-color: #404040;
 color: #000;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#number2 {
 background-color: #777;
 margin-left: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #404040;
 border-radius: 4px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 80px;
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Roboto Mono;
 font-weight: lighter;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
#number2:hover {
 background-color: #404040;
 color: #000;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#number3 {
 background-color: #777;
 margin-left: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #404040;
 border-radius: 4px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 80px;
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Roboto Mono;
 font-weight: lighter;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
#number3:hover {
 background-color: #404040;
 color: #000;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#number4 {
 background-color: #777;
 margin-left: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #404040;
 border-radius: 4px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 80px;
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Roboto Mono;
 font-weight: lighter;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
#number4:hover {
 background-color: #404040;
 color: #000;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#number5 {
 background-color: #777;
 margin-left: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #404040;
 border-radius: 4px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 80px;
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Roboto Mono;
 font-weight: lighter;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
#number5:hover {
 background-color: #404040;
 color: #000;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#number6 {
 background-color: #777;
 margin-left: 1px;
 border: 1px solid #404040;
 border-radius: 4px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 80px;
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Roboto Mono;
 font-weight: lighter;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
#number6:hover {
 background-color: #404040;
 color: #000;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>13 21 11</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto Mono"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div onclick="ups()" id="halfCircle"></div>
  <div id="lock"></div>
  <div id="locker"></div>
  <div id="code">
   <div align="center" onclick="incN1()" id="number1"></div>
   <div align="center" onclick="incN2()" id="number2"></div>
   <div align="center" onclick="incN3()" id="number3"></div>
   <div align="center" onclick="incN4()" id="number4"></div>
   <div align="center" onclick="incN5()" id="number5"></div>
   <div align="center" onclick="incN6()" id="number6"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Here is a link to my game:

[My combination lock](http://www.enigma132111.afonsohipolito.website/132111lock.html)

### Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is only running once, when the page first loads (and the condition is therefore obviously `false`). It looks like you want to check the combination each time the user increments a number - in that case put that checking code in a function and call it inside each of the functions `incN1` etc.